# How to detect Android Split Screen Resizing from Web View?

Tags: javascript, android, split-screen

We are working on a webpage that is currently having issues with split screen resizing.

When we change the orientation of the page on a mobile browser or do a window resize on a desktop browser, we are able to run the required updates fine because we listen to the resize and orientationchange events that get fired with either type of event.

However, we just realized that with split screen on Android (and possibly split screen on iOS tablets), we aren't triggering any resize events for the window and therefore can't do proper updating of our elements based on the split screen being activated or updated (when the user moves the split).

Is this something we can work around or am I just completely missing some functionality that I should be using?

I have looked around online and haven't found anything related so far that I could use from our JS.

Thanks! Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

- [Information about Multi-Window Feature in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) - doesn't go over any possible ways to detect it from a web view though, but looks at it from an Android app dev perspective

Comment: If your page is being viewed in a Web browser, the details likely would be specific to that browser. If your page is being viewed in a `WebView`, you would use the "Android app dev perspective" and forward events to your JavaScript code.